# show the result of a sum with a button with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

first of all im a beginner on programming , so i made a form on html with javascript, the mechanic is simple : you have to chose an option (radio button) for every question, so every choice is part of a big sum of every choice we made, at the end with a button you have to show result of your form, my problem is when i chose an option of a question it shows me the result of that question in that moment and not when i click the show result button. This is my code, thanks for helping me.

```js
var valor1 = 0; //preg 1
var valor2 = 0; //preg2
var valor3 = 0; //preg3
var valor4 = 0; //preg4
var valor5 = 0; //preg5
var valor6 = 0; //preg6
var valor7 = 0; //preg7
var valor8 = 0; //preg8
var valor9 = 0; //preg9
var valor10 = 0; //preg10
var valor11 = 0; //preg11
var valor12 = 0; //preg12
var valor13 = 0; //preg13
var valor14 = 0; //preg14
var valor15 = 0; //preg15
var valor16 = 0; //preg16
var valor17 = 0; //preg17
var valor18 = 0; //preg18
var valor19 = 0; //preg19
var valor20 = 0; //preg20
    
function sumar(radio) {
    var valor = parseInt(radio.value);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta1")
        valor1 = parseInt (valor); 
    if (radio.name == "pregunta2")
        valor2 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta3")
        valor3 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta4")
        valor4 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta5")
        valor5 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta6")
        valor6 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta7")
        valor7 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta8")
        valor8 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta9")
        valor9 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta10")
        valor10 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta11")
        valor11 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta12")
        valor12 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta13")
        valor13 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta14")
        valor14 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta15")
        valor15 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta16")
        valor16 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta17")
        valor17 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta18")
        valor18 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta19")
        valor19 = parseInt (valor);
    if (radio.name == "pregunta20")
        valor20 = parseInt (valor);
    valor = parseInt (valor1+valor2+valor3+valor4+valor5+valor6+valor7+valor8+valor9+valor10+valor11+valor12+valor13+valor14+valor15+valor16+valor17+valor18+valor19+valor20);  
     alert ("su resultado es:"+valor);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>1- Soy una persona con muchas cualidades.   </legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta1" id="radiogroup1_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta1" id="radiogroup1_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1"  id="radiogroup1_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
                                     
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>2- Por lo general, si tengo algo que decir lo digo.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta2" id="radiogroup2_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta2" id="radiogroup2_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta2"  id="radiogroup2_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>3- Con frecuencia me avergüenzo de mi mismo.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta3" id="radiogroup3_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta3" id="radiogroup3_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta3"  id="radiogroup3_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>4- Casi siempre me siento seguro de lo que pienso.</legend>
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta4" id="radiogroup4_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta4" id="radiogroup4_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta4"  id="radiogroup4_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>5- En realidad, no me gusto a mi mismo.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta5" id="radiogroup5_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta5" id="radiogroup5_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta5"  id="radiogroup5_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>6- Rara vez me siento culpable de cosas que he hecho.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta6" id="radiogroup6_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta6" id="radiogroup6_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta6"  id="radiogroup6_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>7-Creo que la gente tiene buena opinión de mí.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta7" id="radiogroup7_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta7" id="radiogroup7_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta7"  id="radiogroup7_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>8-Soy bastante feliz.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta8" id="radiogroup8_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta8" id="radiogroup8_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta8"  id="radiogroup8_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>9- Me siento orgulloso de lo que hago.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta9" id="radiogroup9_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta9" id="radiogroup9_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta9"  id="radiogroup9_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>10- Poca gente me hace caso.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta10" id="radiogroup10_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta10" id="radiogroup10_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta10"  id="radiogroup10_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>11- Hay muchas cosas de mí que cambiaría si pudiera.</legend>
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta11" id="radiogroup11_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta11" id="radiogroup11_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta11"  id="radiogroup11_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>12- Me cuesta mucho trabajo hablar delante de la gente.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta12" id="radiogroup12_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta12" id="radiogroup12_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta12"  id="radiogroup12_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>13- Casi nunca estoy triste.</legend>
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta13" id="radiogroup13_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta13" id="radiogroup13_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta13"  id="radiogroup13_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    
    </fieldset>
    
    <br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>  14- Es muy difícil ser uno mismo.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta14" id="radiogroup14_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta14" id="radiogroup14_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta14"  id="radiogroup14_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>15- Es fácil que yo le caiga bien a la gente.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta15" id="radiogroup15_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta15" id="radiogroup15_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta15"  id="radiogroup15_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>16- Si pudiéramos volver al pasado y vivir de nuevo, yo sería distinto.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta16" id="radiogroup16_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta16" id="radiogroup16_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta16"  id="radiogroup16_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>17- Por lo general, la gente me hace caso cuando los aconsejo.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta17" id="radiogroup17_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta17" id="radiogroup17_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta17"  id="radiogroup17_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>18- Siempre tiene que haber alguien que me diga que hacer.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta18" id="radiogroup18_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta18" id="radiogroup18_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta18"  id="radiogroup18_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C 
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>19- Con frecuencia desearía ser otra persona.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta19" id="radiogroup19_0"value="1" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta19" id="radiogroup19_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta19"  id="radiogroup19_2" value="3" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
    <legend>20- Me siento bastante seguro de mí mismo.</legend>
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta20" id="radiogroup20_0"value="3" onclick="sumar(this);"> 
     A 
    
    <input type="radio"  name="pregunta20" id="radiogroup20_1" value="2" onclick="sumar(this);">
      B
    
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta20"  id="radiogroup20_2" value="1" onclick="sumar(this);">
       C
    </fieldset>
    
    <p>
    <br>
             <input type="button" onclick="sumar(radio)"    value="Calcular resultado"  >  
        <br />
      </p>
     </form>
```

Comment: Have you heard about arrays?

Comment: If I understand your issue, you would want to remove the onclick calls to your function from each radio input, then change your function logic so that it adds up the selected radio values for each group all at once.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the `sumar` function in the onclick event in the button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="sumar(radio)"    value="Calcular resultado"  >
```

simply add a new function `showResult` and bind it to the on click

```
function showResult() {
    var result = parseInt(valor1 + valor2 + valor3 + valor4 + valor5 + valor6 + valor7 + valor8 + valor9 + valor10 + valor11 + valor12 + valor13 + valor14 + valor15 + valor16 + valor17 + valor18 + valor19 + valor20);
    alert("su resultado es:" + result);
}


<input type="button" onclick="showResult()"    value="Calcular resultado"  >
```

and remove the alert in your sumar function

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufpswd8z/)